# weak reference delegate not restored

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, weak-references, state-restoration

The `AddCityViewController` is restored with its corresponding textfields. The 'Cancel' and 'Save' buttons contain calls to the delegate. The modal view controller is being restored, but the "Save" and "Cancel" buttons are not activating the delegate method. All view controllers have been created inside of storyboard.

```
//  AddCityViewController.h

@class City;

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol addCityDelegate;

@interface AddCityViewController : UIViewController
@property(nonatomic, weak) id <addCityDelegate> delegate;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSManagedObjectContext *context;
@end

@protocol addCityDelegate
- (void)save: (City *)controller withBool:(BOOL )saveStatus;;
@end
```

Cancel button only calls the delegate method when State Restoration is not being implemented.

I want the delegate to also be called when its needed for State Restoration

```
// AddCityViewController.m

- (IBAction)cancelButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
   [self.delegate save:nil withBool:false];
}

#pragma mark - encodeRestorable and decodeRestorable

- (void)encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
   [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
   [coder encodeObject:self.delegate forKey:@"restoreDelegate"];
   [coder encodeObject:self.cityNameLabel.text          
                forKey:@"restoreCountyLabelText"];    
}

-(void)decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    [coder encodeObject:self.delegate forKey:@"restoreDelegate"];
    _cityNameLabel.text = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"restoreCountyLabelText"];

    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
}
```

The `CityTableViewController` is the delegate for the `AddCityTableView`

```
// CityTableViewController.m

  #import "CityTableViewController.h"
  #import "AddCityViewController.h"

  #import "City.h"
  #import "County.h"

  @interface CityTableViewController ()<addCityDelegate>
  @property(nonatomic,strong)NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
  @end
  #pragma mark - AddConjugations Delete
```

...

The below delegate method functions perfectly, except for STATE RESTORATION. During state restoration, this method is never called.

```
 - (void)save: (AddCityViewController *)saveNewCity withBool:(BOOL )saveStatus
 {
    if (saveStatus) {
   ...
 }
```

Comment: It is pretty odd to be archiving the delegate as a part of the archived object graph.  Typically something you'd recreate when the UI becomes available.   Generally.

Comment: I don't know how to recreate the delegate when the view controller is restored. With state restoration, the view controller returns with its textfield text, but self.delegate = (null).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to encode your delegate again instead of decoding it.

**Change your code to:**

```
-(void)decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self.delegate = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"restoreDelegate"];
    _cityNameLabel.text = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"restoreCountyLabelText"];
    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
}
```